# SQLCLR Assembly deployment failed because assembly failed verification

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sqlclr, user-defined-types

In case someone else runs into this problem.

> Error:  SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: ... CREATE ASSEMBLY
>   for assembly 'Assembly.Name' failed because assembly 'Assembly.Name'
>   failed verification. Check if the referenced assemblies are up-to-date
>   and trusted (for external_access or unsafe) to execute in the
>   database. CLR Verifier error messages if any will follow this message
>   [token  0x02000003] Type load failed.

The SQLCLR assembly builds successfully but couldn't be deployed. When the assembly is accessed by regular a .NET application (outside of SQL Server), it will give a `TypeLoadException`:

> Could not load type 'Type.In.Assembly' from assembly
>   'Assembly.Name, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' because the format is invalid.

The problem is related to the User-Defined Type (UDT) within the assembly.

Comment: Thanks for posting this info :)

Answer (score 4):

The culprit is

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute

When we define a UDT using
`[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlUserDefinedType(Format.Native)]` 
and the UDT is a class (instead of a struct) it is required to also define a
`[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]` on the class.

The problem was my UDT class was inheriting from a base class. **The `StructLayout` must be defined on the base class too.**