# SQLCLR assembly registration failed (Type load failed)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sqlclr

I'm trying to register SQLCLR assembly in SqlServer

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [DatabaseCLR]
FROM 'T:\DatabaseCLR.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
GO
```

but during registration I get error message

> Msg 6218, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly
>   'DatabaseCLR' failed because assembly 'DatabaseCLR' failed
>   verification. Check if the referenced assemblies are up-to-date and
>   trusted (for external_access or unsafe) to execute in the database.
>   CLR Verifier error messages if any will follow this message
> [ :
>   DatabaseCLR.BinaryUtils::HasSetBits][mdToken=0x6000039] Type load
>   failed.
> [token  0x02000008] Type load failed.

which is similar to one described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39741896/2523686) question. However the situation is a bit different. In my assembly I do not use User-Defined Types.

If I use`PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE` the assembly registers successfully. It doesn't seem that I use unsafe code though ("Allow unsafe code" checkbox is not checked in project properties) (or do I?).

The assembly code (simplified) is:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

namespace DatabaseCLR
{
    public class BinaryUtils
    {
        [SqlFunction(Name = "BinaryHasSetBits", IsDeterministic = true, IsPrecise = true)]
        public static SqlBoolean HasSetBits(SqlBytes data)
        {
            if (data.IsNull)
                return SqlBoolean.Null;

            if (data.Storage != StorageState.Buffer)
                throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("Storage type {0} is not supported.", data.Storage));

            long
                len = data.Length,
                ulen = len / sizeof(ulong),
                tail = len % sizeof(ulong);

            ByteToUlongConverter conv = new ByteToUlongConverter(data.Buffer);
            for (long i = 0; i < ulen; i++)
                if (conv.ulongs[i] != 0)
                    return SqlBoolean.True;

            for (long i = len - tail; i < len; i++)
                if (data.Buffer[i] != 0)
                    return SqlBoolean.True;

            return SqlBoolean.False;
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    internal struct ByteToUlongConverter
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public byte[] bytes;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public ulong[] ulongs;

        public ByteToUlongConverter(byte[] bytes)
        {
            this.ulongs = null;
            this.bytes = bytes;
        }
    }
}
```

The assembly provides functions for bitwise operations on binary types. I'm using `struct` with `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]` attribute for casting `byte[]` array to `ulong[]` array (to speed up processing). I guess that use of `StructLayout` causes error as in the related question. However it is not on UDT, and I do not see how I can fix it in this case.

Are there any chances to register assembly with `PERMISSION_SET = SAFE` ?

---

I do register my sample function as

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.BinaryHasSetBits
(
    @data varbinary(8000)
)
RETURNS BIT
AS EXTERNAL NAME [DatabaseCLR].[DatabaseCLR.BinaryUtils].[HasSetBits]
GO
```

---

I'm using x64 editions of

- SqlServer 2014 (assembly compiled for .Net 4.0)
- SqlServer 2008 (assembly compiled for .Net 2.0)

Comment: Do you need the using interopServices? Do you need structLayout and FieldLayout?

Comment: please, inform witch sql server and .net version.

Comment: Better tag it, some sqlclr errors are due to some incompatibility between sql server version and .net version.

Comment: First of all - yes, your code us actually unsafe, possibility to violate checkbox is just compiler feature. The second - why you think your solution will be faster than searching in bytes array, something like Array.Exists(data.Buffer,b=>b!=0)

Comment: @vitalygolub, _mscorlib_ is in the [supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403279.aspx) list, so I'm surprised that I should use `PERMISSION_SET=UNSAFE`. I did tested two approaches under Profiler (treating `byte[]` as `ulong[]` allows data to be processed faster than treating `byte[]` as it is).

Comment: @srutzky, yes, if possible (though it seems that I have to choose between speed and safety in this case). I'm open if there is another safe speeding-up alternative.

Comment: it is unsafe because of System.Runtime.InteropServices; [look, for example, here](https://books.google.fi/books?id=13ayznPwlysC&pg=PA193&lpg=PA193&dq=does+System.Runtime.InteropServices+require+unsafe+permission+for+sql+clr&source=bl&ots=OhMP6pWmGa&sig=ACfU3U22UgYSg0qrxtkkpYjq7shpXVD9sA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjO0NyQ6MrlAhUh_CoKHT2rDIYQ6AEwAXoECBgQAQ#v=onepage&q=does%20System.Runtime.InteropServices%20require%20unsafe%20permission%20for%20sql%20clr&f=false).

Comment: @Oleksandr, AFAIR, it is due to use of `LayoutKind.Explicit`, changing it to `LayoutKind.Sequential` allows registering with `PERMISSION_SET = SAFE`. But use of `LayoutKind.Sequential` breaks intended semantics. So, `SAFE` or `Explicit`, not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to use of `LayoutKind.Explicit`.

Changing it to `LayoutKind.Sequential`

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct ByteToUlongConverter
{
    ...
}
```

makes possible registering assembly with `PERMISSION_SET = SAFE`.

But using `LayoutKind.Sequential` instead of `LayoutKind.Explicit` breaks semantics in this case.

So, `PERMISSION_SET = SAFE` or `LayoutKind.Explicit`, not both.